# Multi level associations in Sequelize.js

Tags: sequelize.js

```
Entry.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: AddressBook,
            include: [{
                model: Account,
                where: {
                    id: req.accountId
                }
            }]
        }],
        limit: req.query.limit,
        offset: req.query.offset,
        order: req.query.order
    }).then(function(result) {
        res.json(result);
    }, function(err) {
        res.status(404).send(err);
    })
```

I am trying to send the user all the entries that belong to a certain account. Each entry belongs to an address book and each address book to an account. When the user receives the JSON with the entry the AddressBook and Account info is also included. I want that information to be excluded, however i also want to make sure that only the entries that belong to a specific account are sent.

```
var onlyEntry = result.get({plain: true});
delete onlyEntry.AddressBook;
res.json(onlyEntry);
```

This works but is an ugly solution.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is it  is a problem to have the account and address book info included?

Comment: I don't want to send unnecessary information through the api. Basically i am looking for a way to filter what is being sent back.